# MySql Trigger Function about status

Tags: mysql, sql, date, database-trigger, sql-view

I would like to ask a solution for mysql database. since i made database(order) about 3 column named as order_date(datatype - date),expired_date(datatype - date) and status(varchar(10)).

*as status value are only New and Expired.[as only 'New' input from user]*

The main process I want is

- as expired date(calculated from order_date) should know that currentday is doing well
- if currentday is greater than expired date. database should be triggered and update status column 'New' into 'Expired'

as far I know to accomplish this I should use an SQL trigger. How can I implement a trigger for the above use case.

Comment: Don't do it. Your database already knows which status it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for an `update` statement that you would run periodically, and that sets the status of newly expired items, that would be:

```
update orders
set status = 'expired'
where curent_date > expired_date and status = 'new'
```

---

On the other hand... In your schema, `status` is a *derived* information, that is a column whose value can be inferred from the values of other columns. I would not recommend actually storing this information, because it would require an additional and tedious maintenance process.

Instead, you can create a view that computes the information on the fly when queried, and gives you an always up-to-date perspective at your data.

```
create view view_orders as
select
    order_date,
    expired_date,
    case when curent_date > expired_date then 'expired' else 'new' end status
from orders
```

Comment: but  i want in update in database  that can open anytime.since i open today then database should know that current_date